# Which type of indexing is required in Neo4j for search from many type of Labels in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are using Fulltext indexing in Spring Data Neo4j 3.2.0 from this http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.2.0.M1/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-reference.pdf
like this

`@Indexed(indexName = "peopleSearch", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT) String title` but this is in Job Domain , we have other Domain as well like Event Domain , Task Domain and in them we also have "title" property.

So we need indexing like if user wants to search "XYZ" then it search from title property from Job,Event,Task Domain .

So how we can achieve that from Neo4j

Answer (score 0):

We get a solution

```
@Indexed(indexName = "peopleSearch", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
     String postText

 @Indexed(indexName = "peopleSearch", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT) String username
```

And then in Cypher we use

```
START item=node:peopleSearch("postText:v* OR username:*a")
 return id(item) ,labels(item)
```

If you have any better approach then Provide us . 
Thanks

Comment: START item=node:peopleSearch("postText:v* OR username:*a")
WHERE item:Job
 return id(item) ,labels(item)